# Unhandled exceptions in jQuery 2.2.1 ("Cannot find function createHTMLDocument in object" & "Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string")

Tags: javascript, jquery, raygun.io

I've recently updated from an older 1.x version of jQuery to the latest 2.2.1 and mostly it seems to be running just fine. Unfortunately I'm constantly receiving 2 error messages in raygun which I don't know how to handle:

The first one is `Cannot find function createHTMLDocument in object` and only happens in `Firefox 24.0` under `Win 7` (according to raygun).

The second one states `Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string` and only happens in `Firefox 38.0` in the OS reported as `Linux Core`.

Both errors don't provide any stack trace (`at function () line null, column null (null:null)`) and I can't reproduce neither one myself using the same FF & OS version using browserstack.

I'm not quite sure if those errors where already happening earlier in the older jQuery version since I was loading this version from a different CDN which didn't provide any useful errors from within jQuery at raygun at all due to same origin stuff.

One more thing: If it turns out, that those errors actually happen in some legacy browsers which just report an incorrect version 24 & 38, I'd also be happy to know, how to detect those browsers early so that I can show them an appropriate message before the errors occur.

I'd really appreciate any help/input on how to tackle this issue since I'm a little clueless by now.

Thanks